# Puppeteer worked in MacOS but not in Windows

Tags: javascript, node.js, windows, macos, puppeteer

I have make a node script that uses puppeteer on **MacOS**. The script just launches puppeteer and intercept requests.

Here is the part of the code that uses puppeteer:

```
const getAllUrls = async (rootUrl) => {
    const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
    const urls = [];
    await puppeteer.launch().then(async browser => {
        const page = await browser.newPage();
        await page.setRequestInterception(true);
        page.on('request', interceptedRequest => {
            if (isRelevantUrl(interceptedRequest.url())) {
                urls.push(interceptedRequest.url());
                interceptedRequest.abort();
            } else {
                interceptedRequest.continue();
            }
        });
        await page.goto(rootUrl);
        await browser.close()
    })
    .catch(err => console.log(err));

    return urls;

}
```

While running it on **MacOS** the script works great. But when I try running it on my office with **Windows** I get the following error message:

> Error: Failed to launch chrome!
>
> TROUBLESHOOTING: 
>   https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/troubleshooting.md
>
> at onClose
>   (C:\Users........\node_modules\puppeteer\lib\Launcher.js:339:14) at
>   ChildProcess.helper.addEventListener
>   (C:\Users........\node_modules\puppeteer\lib\Launcher.js:329:60)

I have tried the following config recommended by puppeteer troubleshooting:

```
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
  ignoreDefaultArgs: ['--disable-extensions'],
});
```

But it didn't helped.

I have hard copied the script (without node-modules of course) and paste it on the project at my office. Then did `npm i`.
The rest of the packages used on the script worked good on Windows as well.

Please help.

Comment: did you try manually installing puppeteer on the windows machine?  I think I ran into something similar last year when porting my mac-developed code over to windows.

Comment: @tamak what do you mean by manually installing? Installing it without doing npm i puppeteer ? How? I don't think that would solve my issue...

Comment: Your code runs OK in my Mac, but i've make some changes. I've make dummy function `isRelevantUrl` that returns any call to `true` and `false` (I've try both).
 I'm really suspicious with this function - `isRelevantUrl`. Can you post this source ?

Try to deploy your code once more only `package.json` and try to `npm install` again. Also try to comment the `await browser.close()`

Comment: @EdiImanto on Mac it works fine. The problem is on Windows. I have even tried just doing `puppeteer.launch()` and I get the same error. `isRelevantUrl()` just return true or false depending if the url have some specific sub-string so it's not really "relevant" lol.
I feel like there might be a problem with Chromium path when running it on Windows or so...